# wxWidgets 3.1.3 icon loading under mac - ICNS files unreadable?

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

It now seems impossible to load .icns files under mac. It used to be possible using wxIcon and wxIconLocation, eg.

```
wxMimeTypesManager manager;
wxFileType *type = manager.GetFileTypeFromExtension("zip");
wxIconLocation location;
if(type->GetIcon(&location))
{
  // location m_filename is something like "/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Archive Utility.app/Contents/Resources/bah-zip.icns"
  wxIcon icon;
  // This will FAIL now as there is no handler for wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON...
  icon.LoadFile(location.GetFileName(), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON, 32, 32);
}
```

wxMimeTypesManager::GetFileTypeFromExtension returns a wxFileType.
You can then use wxFileType::GetIcon to return a wxIconLocation.

wxIconLocation::GetFileName() returns a .icns file under OSX. This used to be loadable as a wxIcon under wxWidgets 2.9.1 if you passed wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON to wxIcon::LoadFile as this forced wxIcon::LoadIconFromFile (src/osx/carbon/icon.cpp) to load from an icns using ReadIconFromFSRef.

But since all the Carbon code has gone, now I cannot load anything from an .icns file.

How can I do this now?

EDIT: I used the following configure:
`configure --disable-shared --enable-unicode --prefix="$(pwd)" --enable-stc --enable-ipc --enable-base64 --enable-exceptions --enable-fontenum --enable-fs_archive --enable-stdpaths --enable-sysoptions --enable-threads --enable-url --enable-aui  --enable-graphics_ctx  --enable-printarch --enable-timer --enable-ribbon --enable-webview --enable-display --enable-splash --enable-snglinst --enable-printfposparam --with-opengl --with-osx_cocoa --with-expat=builtin --with-cxx=11 --enable-cxx11 --enable-stl --enable-std_iostreams --enable-std_string --enable-ftp --enable-http --enable-fileproto --enable-sockets --enable-ipv6 --enable-dataobj --enable-ipc --enable-any --enable-arcstream --enable-backtrace --enable-cmdline --enable-datetime --enable-debugreport --enable-dynamicloader --enable-exceptions --enable-ffile --enable-file --enable-filehistory --enable-filesystem --enable-fontmap --enable-fs_inet --enable-fs_zip --enable-fsvolume --enable-fswatcher --enable-geometry --enable-sound --enable-stopwatch --enable-streams --enable-tarstream --enable-textbuf --enable-textfile --enable-variant --enable-zipstream --enable-protocol --enable-protocol-http --enable-protocol-ftp --enable-protocol-file --enable-html --enable-htmlhelp --enable-propgrid --enable-svg --enable-clipboard --enable-dnd --enable-accel --with-osx_cocoa --enable-debug --with-libpng=builtin --with-libjpeg=builtin --with-zlib=builtin --with-libtiff=builtin`

Comment: How did you configured wxWidgets? What was the exact configure line?

Comment: I have edited the post to indicate the configure I used as I cannot add it as a comment. Thanks BTW.

Comment: most of those options are redundant if not all of them as they are "on" by default. Anyway as Vadim said - it looks like this is just an un-implemented feature. As a temporary workaround try Vadim' suggestion. If it won't work - you can file a bug at trac.wxwidgets.org or try to implement it yourself.

Comment: Yes I deliberately "turn on" options in the configure in case the default ever changes and prefer to be explicit. I will try VZ's suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me, unfortunately. Currently `wxIcon::LoadIconFromFile()` simply always returns false when `wxOSX_ICON_USE_NSIMAGE==1`, which is the default. You could try setting `wxOSX_BITMAP_NATIVE_ACCESS` to 0 in `setup.h` and rebuilding as a very short term fix, but what really needs to be done is implementing this function using NSImage, probably using `[NSImage initWithContentsOfFile:]`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try ```wxOSX_BITMAP_NATIVE_ACCESS``` and then look into ```initWithContentsOfFile``` out of interest. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to turn `wxOSX_BITMAP_NATIVE_ACCESS` _off_, it's on by default. See also [this ticket](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/18647).

Comment: I rebuilt with ```include/wx/osx/setup.h``` ```wxOSX_BITMAP_NATIVE_ACCESS``` set to 0 and the code in the initial question still did not succeed, as there is no handler for ```wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON``` still. I could try another type, but any suggestions as to which? Thanks